# Opening A PopUp from outside Marker Component

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

Hey so I am attempting to open a PopUp on a component by clicking an outside reference. I can not seem to find a way to manually open a PopUp. I have list of Markers outside of The Map and when one is clicked on I would like to display the popup. I have found a way to designate which marker is the one that should have the popup, I just can't trigger the event. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I am recreating

http://transportation.austintexas.io/signals-on-flash/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by creating a CustomMarker component and having it extend Marker class, and called bindPopup in ComponentWillMount()

```
export default class CustomMarker extends Marker{
componentWillMount(){
    super.componentWillMount();
    console.log(this.props.info);
    this.leafletElement.bindPopup('foo')
}
```

Then I called

```
export default class CustomMarker extends Marker{
componentWillMount(){
    super.componentWillMount();
    console.log(this.props.info);
    this.leafletElement.bindPopup('foo')
}
```

Then Called `ref={open ? this.simulateClick : null}` on the Marker Element

and `simulateClick()` looks like this

```
simulateClick = marker => {
    if(marker){
        marker.leafletElement.openPopup();
    }
};
```